# when UITextField is focused and scribble is on,keyboard don't show

Tags: swift, ipad, scribble, apple-pencil

there

I'm making drawing app on iPad with iOS14.

this app enables to use apple pencil.

I'm facing a problem.

when i try to write a text on UITextField by scribble hand write,keyboard don't showing.

my client said it can be enabled keyboard writing when scribble hand write is on.

is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this quite late but I'll still try to give you (or people looking for the same answer lates) some useful information:

1. I don't think that you can use "normal" keyboard with pencil (although it will appear immediately after you touch text field with your finger)
2. You can use pencil to show small screen keyboard by tapping the Scribble toolbar (usually bottom left corner, small icon of pencil tip) and then keyboard button, see [here](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/ipad/ipad355ab2a7/ipados)

Hope it will be helpful :)